# Unable to resolve service for type with our own class

Tags: asp.net-web-api, .net-core, inversion-of-control

We are getting this exception when calling a web api controller:

> InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'SDS.Lambda.Interfaces.ISecretManager' while attempting to activate 'SDS.Lambda.Controllers.SapController'.\r\n                <p class="location">Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.GetService(IServiceProvider sp, Type type, Type requiredBy, bool isDefaultParameterRequired)

`StartUp.cs` contains the following:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddSingleton<ISecretManager, SecretManager>();
}
```

The controller has this constructor:

```
public class SapController : Controller
{
    public SapController(ISecretManager secretManager)
    {
        _secretManager = secretManager;
    }
}
```

We have the same issue with other types being injected into the constructor, but the IConfiguration instance can be injected, for example that parameter does not cause an exception:

```
public SapController(IConfiguration configuration, ISecretManager secretManager)
```

The ISecretManager interface looks like this (yes, it really does):

```
namespace SDS.Lambda.Interfaces
{
    public interface ISecretManager
    {
    }
}
```

And the class (yes, really - I reduced it down to avoid complexity):

```
namespace SDS.Lambda.Interfaces
{
    public class SecretManager : ISecretManager
    {
    }
}
```

Are we providing the interface/concrete type incorrectly?

Is there a way to retrieve the concrete type to test whether it has been provided properly?

When execution reaches the bottom of `ConfigureServices`, if we look at the `services` instance result enumeration, in the debugger view, the types we are injecting are listed, so we can't see why they are failing to be instantiated.

**UPDATE**

To elaborate and explain the issue with another class/dependency in the same solution:

Controller:

```
namespace SDS.Lambda.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class SapController : Controller
    {
        readonly IHelper helper;

        public SapController(IHelper helpme)
        {
            helper = helpme;
        }
...
}
```

Interface:

```
namespace SDS.Lambda.Interfaces
{
    public interface IHelper
    {
    }
}
```

Class:

```
namespace SDS.Lambda.Helpers
{
    public class Helper : IHelper
    {
        public Helper()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

StartUp:

```
namespace SDS.Lambda
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public static IConfiguration Configuration { get; private set; }
        private readonly AppSettings _appSettings;

        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
            _appSettings = configuration.GetSection("AppSettings").Get<AppSettings>();
        }

        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddLogging(logger => logger.AddLambdaLogger());
            
            services.AddSingleton<IHelper, Helper>();
            
            services.AddControllers();
        }
...
}
```

Comment: Does `SecretManager` implementation's constructor have all injected dependencies registered with the container? Show `SecretManager` constructor and also where its dependencies (if any) are also added to services  collection in `Startup`

Comment: I've added the secret manager class and interface to my post. As you can see, they are very bare and have no dependencies. I even created a completely separate class just to prove that this is not a one-off and that did not get resolved either.

Comment: I just added the class definition for the controller, to show it's inheritance.

Comment: So `SecretManager` uses a default constructor? what happens in its constructor if anything at all. In order to troubleshoot the issue we need to see higher up the stack since what you have shown about the controller should work by default.

Comment: I've added the extra example class/interface which should be getting injected but is not. The code it literally as you see it.